Unable to create AWS Batch Job-Definition of Fargate type
I am referring to aws_batch_job_definition – Manage AWS Batch Job Definitions — Ansible Documentation page in-order to create aws job-definition.
As mentioned, we can create a container type of job-definition.  But my requirement is to create a job-definition of type Fargate
- name: My Batch Job Definition
  batch_job_definition:
    job_definition_name: My Batch Job Definition
    state: present
    type: container
    parameters:
      Param1: Val1
      Param2: Val2
    image: <Docker Image URL>
    vcpus: 1
    memory: 512
    command:
      - python
      - run_my_script.py
      - arg1
    job_role_arn: <Job Role ARN>
    attempts: 3
  register: job_definition_create_result

